# How do I complete registration for a live application on PayPal

Tags: paypal, registration

I have been using the Express Checkout methods of the PayPal Classic API to allow my site's clients to set up both recurring and one-off payments. Everything works smoothly in my test environment with it pointing to the PayPal sandbox environment.

Now I have been trying to go live. I am following the instructions from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/ which tells me to register my app. I go to https://apps.paypal.com/user/my-account/applications/new and fill in my details, but in the section 'Services used by App' there is nowhere to tick Merchant Services. I'm not using the Adaptive API or Invoicing, but the page won't allow me to submit without filling in something on the Adaptive Payments section. There is no help or guidance on the page.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just using Express Checkout and Recurring Payments you won't need to submit an app. The app submission is for people using Adaptive Payment or Adaptive Account API calls.

You should be able to use Express Checkout as long as you have a confirmed and Verified Business PayPal account.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is true now. The [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/) seems to suggest you have to submit any app: *"If your application makes calls to the PayPal Merchant APIs (such as Express Checkout), you can begin making production calls using the credentials assigned to your PayPal account as soon as you register your application. PayPal reviews your application within 24 – 72 hours of your submission to ensure it complies with all requirements. After the review, PayPal grants final approval to your application."*

Comment: Admittedly the app submission form has all the problems described in the question.

Comment: Also, the following page does not mention submitting an Express Checkout app for review, which supports your answer: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGoingLive/