# How to move PayPal Checkout to live production?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I've set up a PayPal Checkout button with my sandbox account, which works, and now I want to change it to use my live business account. There seems to be conflicting information out there on what to do next:

1. The [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/production/#register-your-application-with-paypal) say that I need to submit my app for approval (but it doesn't say how)
2. [This stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075807/how-do-i-complete-registration-for-a-live-application-on-paypal) says that with PayPal Checkout you don't need to submit your app for approval
3. In `paypal.php` (I'm using laravel) there is a parameter called `PAYPAL_LIVE_APP_ID`, which I didn't need with the `sandbox` and I've been trying to find. [This stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482854/how-do-i-get-an-application-id-for-paypal) from 2016 tries to find the `app id` but all links provided there are broken. Do I need the `app id` for PayPal Checkout?

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when I set the `PAYPAL_MODE` in `.env` from `sandbox` to `live`, the PayPal button in my app stops working and shows:

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_RESOURCE_ID
    at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&style.height=45&style.menuPlacement=below&sdkVersion=5.0.332&components.0=buttons&locale.country=GB&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVNWTnlaeTZ0TkdYTnJ4aFhzSXdGLUhKckN4U1NZb1VHVlozd3NqNXVRN3FmMGp4RFAtLXBmTHlUcjUxUnNGVzh0bXFtcnNtYlB4N0VBUWYmZGlzYWJsZS1mdW5kaW5nPWNhcmQsZ2lyb3BheSxzZXBhLHNvZm9ydCZjdXJyZW5jeT1FVVIiLCJhdHRycyI6eyJkYXRhLXVpZCI6InVpZF93cXN2eHlzd3lwcmp6YWdpc21haWduaGlxZXdyZmkifX0&clientID=ASVNyZy6tNGXNrxhXsIwF-HJrCxSSYoUGVZ3wsj5uQ7qf0jxDP--pfLyTr51RsFW8tmqmrsmbPx7EAQf&sdkCorrelationID=f374804ab30b1&storageID=uid_9a4b452c76_mdc6mdi6mjm&sessionID=uid_7aec7bdf11_mdk6nda6nde&buttonSessionID=uid_79a5ce6aa1_mdk6nda6nde&env=sandbox&buttonSize=medium&fundingEligibility=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&platform=mobile&experiment.enableVenmo=false&experiment.enableVenmoAppLabel=false&flow=purchase&currency=EUR&intent=capture&commit=true&vault=false&disableFunding.0=card&disableFunding.1=giropay&disableFunding.2=sepa&disableFunding.3=sofort&renderedButtons.0=paypal&debug=false&applePaySupport=false&supportsPopups=true&supportedNativeBrowser=true&experience=&allowBillingPayments=true:1320:46529
    at n.dispatch (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&style.height=45&style.menuPlacement=below&sdkVersion=5.0.332&components.0=buttons&locale.country=GB&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz9jbGllbnQtaWQ9QVNWTnlaeTZ0TkdYTnJ4aFhzSXdGLUhKckN4U1NZb1VHVlozd3NqNXVRN3FmMGp4RFAtLXBmTHlUcjUxUnNGVzh0bXFtcnNtYlB4N0VBUWYmZGlzYWJsZS1mdW5kaW5nPWNhcmQsZ2lyb3BheSxzZXBhLHNvZm9ydCZjdXJyZW5jeT1FVVIiLCJhdHRycyI6eyJkYXRhLXVpZCI6InVpZF93cXN2eHlzd3lwcmp6YWdpc21haWduaGlxZXdyZmkifX0&clientID=ASVNyZy6tNGXNrxhXsIwF-HJrCxSSYoUGVZ3wsj5uQ7qf0jxDP--pfLyTr51RsFW8tmqmrsmbPx7EAQf&sdkCorrelationID=f374804ab30b1&storageID=uid_9a4b452c76_mdc6mdi6mjm&sessionID=uid_7aec7bdf11_mdk6nda6nde&buttonSessionID=uid_79a5ce6aa1_mdk6nda6nde&env=sandbox&buttonSize=medium&fundingEligibility=eyJwYXlwYWwiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOnRydWUsInZhdWx0YWJsZSI6dHJ1ZX0sInBheWxhdGVyIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZSwicHJvZHVjdHMiOnsicGF5SW4zIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZSwidmFyaWFudCI6bnVsbH0sInBheUluNCI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2UsInZhcmlhbnQiOm51bGx9LCJwYXlsYXRlciI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2UsInZhcmlhbnQiOm51bGx9fX0sImNhcmQiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlLCJicmFuZGVkIjp0cnVlLCJpbnN0YWxsbWVudHMiOmZhbHNlLCJ2ZW5kb3JzIjp7InZpc2EiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOnRydWUsInZhdWx0YWJsZSI6dHJ1ZX0sIm1hc3RlcmNhcmQiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOnRydWUsInZhdWx0YWJsZSI6dHJ1ZX0sImFtZXgiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOnRydWUsInZhdWx0YWJsZSI6dHJ1ZX0sImRpc2NvdmVyIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZSwidmF1bHRhYmxlIjp0cnVlfSwiaGlwZXIiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlLCJ2YXVsdGFibGUiOmZhbHNlfSwiZWxvIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZSwidmF1bHRhYmxlIjp0cnVlfSwiamNiIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZSwidmF1bHRhYmxlIjp0cnVlfX0sImd1ZXN0RW5hYmxlZCI6ZmFsc2V9LCJ2ZW5tbyI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJpdGF1Ijp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImNyZWRpdCI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJhcHBsZXBheSI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJzZXBhIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImlkZWFsIjp7ImVsaWdpYmxlIjpmYWxzZX0sImJhbmNvbnRhY3QiOnsiZWxpZ2libGUiOmZhbHNlfSwiZ2lyb3BheSI6eyJlbGlnaWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9LCJlcHMi
```

and:

```
GET https://b.sbox.stats.paypal.com/v2/counter.cgi?p=uid_7aec7bdf11_mdk6nda6nde&s=SMART_PAYMENT_BUTTONS net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information on [that doc page](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/production/#register-your-application-with-paypal) is out of date. An "app id" is only used by Adaptive Payments integrations, which are obsolete and cannot be used for new integrations anyway.

For REST applications, a live "client id" and "secret" can be created in the [dashboard My Apps & Credentials](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications). They do not require any additional approval/registration unless you are using partner (multi-party) or log in with PayPal features.

The error "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID" is usually caused by mixing things from sandbox and live. Ensure that:

- The `<script>` element with src `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=` specifies a live client ID, not a sandbox/test one.
- Any fetch calls the button code might make (if using a [server integration pattern](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)) retrieve a newly-created and valid live order ID or classic API EC token, not a sandbox one. The browser dev tools "Network" tab is useful for debugging and verifying such an XHR is working.
- Any plan_id (if using a Subscription button) was created with the corresponding live client ID .. not a different client ID nor a sandbox one.